# How to block all the interrupts in linux

Tags: 12.04, bash, python, command-line

I am working on a python project, Where i am displaying a graphical window with log in screen, I've also disabled the close, re size and minimize buttons

My problem:

I have to disable all the interrupts, including disabling system shortcuts like alt + tab, alt + f4 etc, so that user can log in only after entering the username and passwords on the screen.

```
Is there any linux command or any bash script is there ? 

platform : ubuntu
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Cross-posted (please don't do this) at U&L.SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97768/46659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use the following commands:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = "
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = "
```

both <kbd>Alt</kbd> (left and right) will be disabled/blocked. In the same mode you can disable <kbd>Tab</kbd>, respectively <kbd>F4</kbd>:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 23 = "
xmodmap -e "keycode 70 = "
```

To enable them back to their normal behavior, use:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
xmodmap -e "keycode  23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab"
xmodmap -e "keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4"
```

Use `xmodmap -pke` command to see all keycodes and their map assignment.

Comment: thanks for the help, how to block tab? ex: xmodmap -e "keycode 23 = " whatToWriteHere